# find attendance on bases of class,start date and end date

Tags: sql-server

```
USE [Montessorischool] GO /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetAttn1]    Script Date: 8/28/2017 10:33:44 AM ******/ SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO ALTER proc [dbo].[GetAttn1] @startdate date, @enddate date, @class1 varchar(20)

as
--DECLARE @startdate int
--DECLARE @enddate int
--declare @strdays NVARCHAR(4000) declare @cols NVARCHAR(4000) DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(4000) DECLARE @where VARCHAR(20) begin

   --select @startdate from att    --union ALL    --select @startdate 
+ 1 from att       --where    @startdate < @enddate  into #Dates  ;

SELECT DISTINCT Date1 INTO #Dates FROM att where Date1 between @startdate and @enddate ORDER BY Date1;

SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ', ['+ convert(varchar(50),DATEPART(d,Date1),106) + ']', '['+ convert(varchar(50),DATEPART(d,Date1),106) + ']')  from    #Dates ;


SET @qry =

'SELECT * FROM (SELECT name, status,class, DATEPART(d,Date1) Date1 FROM att) tbldate  PIVOT (MAX(status) FOR Date1 IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat';



Execute(@qry)  

-- Dropping temporary tables DROP TABLE #Dates;

end GetAttn1 '2017-08-10','2017-08-30','LKG'

Blockquote
```

Out put is as

```
Ashok       LKG NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
A Krishan   LKG P       P       P       A       A       NULL 
Naveen      LKG P       P       P       P       P       NULL 
Santosh     LKG P       A       P       P       P       NULL 
Ashok       Pre NULL    NULL    NULL    P       NULL    NULL 
Sachin      UKG NULL    NULL    P       NULL    NULL    NULL
```

but i need

```
Ashok       LKG NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL NULL   
A Krishan   LKG P       P       P       A       A    NULL 
Naveen      LKG P       P       P       P       P    NULL 
Santosh     LKG P       A       P       P       P    NULL
```

Comment: please explain what are you trying to do. What you want to achive. Also provide some sample data for the expected result

Comment: i have table name att whcih have store attendance of student lkg,ukg and pre . I want to see attendance only one class(which provide at run time) at one time from start date to end date   expected data shown in i need

Answer (score 0):

change your @qry to

```
SET @qry =

'SELECT * FROM (SELECT name, status,class, DATEPART(d,Date1) Date1 FROM att WHERE class = @class1) tbldate  PIVOT (MAX(status) FOR Date1 IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat';
```